# How does GitHub pick "Popular repositories" for organizations when fork and watchers count is equal?

Tags: github

My mind still blows on looking for logic (if any) in which our organization's repositories GitHub picks for "Popular repositories". If [all other factors](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/57373/21486) are equal then the natural logic (?) would be to take more recently updated repo as more popular (?). It isn't working this way.

We have two repositories:

- Both has the same number of forks (**zero**)
- Both has the same number of watchers (**four**)
- One was updated **3 months ago**, the other one -- **3 hours ago**

GitHub always shows the second one as "Popular".

How can be long time not updated repo more popular then the one that receives pushes every day? What is the logic here (if any)? What am I missing?

Since we're talking about organization's repos (and not [private profile ones](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/57373/21486)) then it seems we can't override this with [the usual way](https://github.blog/2016-06-16-pin-repositories-to-your-github-profile/). At least I don't see *Customize your pinned repositories* link. Neither in organization's profile page, nor in the repositories list.

Is there anything we can do to change this... logic?

Comment: @tredjer I'm going to move this to chat so we can speak about it and anyone else can join who cares to be helpful.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148958/discussion-on-question-by-trejder-how-does-github-pick-popular-repositories-fo); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.